# Cordova crosswalk app crash

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I'm using Crosswalk in my cordova app but the app crash.
If I remove Crosswalk, the app run.

Same things with the sample app.

Someone already work with Crosswalk-project ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: after many test, the app run in 4G (cellular) but crash at launch in wifi. any ideas?

Comment: As @MysticMagic said, pleas show the LogCat. Is the app launching and sporadically crashing? Does it never launch? LogCat will tell you

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved by adding the following lines in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: doesn't help. it seems to work well on MacOSX . but on Windows/Ubuntu there still a problem with the built APKs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your Cordova Android platform and execute crosswalk script.

You can get a copy of the script here:

- https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nolanlawson/f332ed32202fe3671769/raw/92d7df5d73cbdbb6cc82d7bc7133d4c62067ba24/prepare_crosswalk.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# usage: provide a path to a crosswalk-cordova-x86 and crosswalk-cordova-arm library,
# run in the current (project) directory, and it will set up crosswalk for you
#
# ./prepare_crosswalk.sh /path/to/crosswalk-cordova-VERSION-x86 /path/to/crosswalk-cordova-VERSION-arm
# 

X86=$1
ARM=$2

if [[ -z $X86 ]]; then
  echo 'usage: ./prepare_crosswalk /path/to/crosswalk-cordova-VERSION-x86 /path/to/crosswalk-cordova-VERSION-arm'
  exit 1
fi

if [[ -z $ARM ]]; then
  echo 'usage: ./prepare_crosswalk /path/to/crosswalk-cordova-VERSION-x86 /path/to/crosswalk-cordova-VERSION-arm'
  exit 1
fi

cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@3.5
rm -fr platforms/android/CordovaLib/*
cp -a $X86/framework/* platforms/android/CordovaLib/
cp -a $ARM/framework/xwalk_core_library/libs/armeabi-v7a platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/libs/
cp $X86/VERSION platforms/android/
cd platforms/android/CordovaLib/
android update project --subprojects --path . --target "android-19"
ant debug
cd -

# sed sucks on a mac, can't do sed -i
cat platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml | sed 's/<\/manifest>/<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" \/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" \/><\/manifest>/' > platforms/android/AndroidManifestNew.xml
mv platforms/android/AndroidManifestNew.xml platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
```