# Cordova App migrated to Crosswalk crashes

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I am have migrated my cordova app to Crosswalk and facing issue while running crosswalk package on my tablet.

Following is the error from error log:
02-01 14:22:04.781: E/SPPClientService(5143): [PushClientApplication] Push log off : This is Release version
02-01 14:22:04.881: E/SMD(185): connect error:22
02-01 14:22:05.191: E/dalvikvm(5162): Could not find class 'org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.makeChromeClient

Any pointers on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding the permissions listed here:
[Cordova crosswalk app crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038216/cordova-crosswalk-app-crash)